# Mosfet is getting hot in switching circuit

Tags: mosfet, switch-mode-power-supply, nimh

I've built a NiMh battery charger (6-cell battery, 7.2v, 3000Mah) using DS2715.
Input is 12v.
Here is the schematic:

[image]

For Q1 I used [IRF9540N](http://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irf9540n.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a401535611caa31dc6)
For Q3 I used [IRLB8721PbF](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/irlb8721pbf.pdf)
L1 is a 47uF ferrite choke
R7 (current sense) is 0.1 Ohm

The diode is blinking and a current flowing to the battery is 0.75A which would indicate that the circuit is assembled correctly.

The problem is that Q1 is getting too hot (can't hold a finger on it for more than a second) even with a small heatsink.
I now it can handle up to 175C, but I thought that in a switching mode it shouldn't be hot.
I know that for linear mode it would need to dissipate (12v - 6v) * 0.75 = 4.5W of power, but in switching mode it shouldn't even need a heatsink.

Can someone help me understand what's going on here? Can I do something to make it cooler (apart from getting a bigger heatsink :))

Here is the datasheet for DS2715:
https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS2715.pdf

And here is the source of the schematic that I've used:
https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/4180

Here is the layout of the thing:
[image]

Cheers!
Leonti

Update:
After using more appropriate mosfets overheating issue went away :)
IRLML2246TRPbF for Q1
FK3503010L for Q3

Accepted answer has the details

Comment: is it possible a poor layout or wiring with ~ 10MHz resonant conduction loss? or other reactive substituions?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I added the layout, could you take a look?

Comment: L1 looks suspiciously like a bad choice. No ground plane can mean awful things are happening when the FET switches on/off.

Comment: But L1 is not connected to the ground. What do you mean by ground plane?

Comment: @Leonti. can't you report any better measurements , like variable NPN active load,  Iout vs Iin to determine efficiency non-linearity or Vin vs In for some loads or anything on a scope with short gnd . In the meantime use a fan. I would measure Vgs vs Is. with spring probe on calibrated 10:1 but IRF part is old high threshold Vth switch and you dont have enough Vgs . I suggest Vgs=2xVth .. try a logic level Vth=1.5 FET or use specified part

Comment: FETs like BJT,s are voltage controlled resistors except different transfer function. BJT's turn on above 0.6V then Rce is inversely dependant on Input current (like variable Pot) until it being saturated up to 1:10 Ib:Ic while FETS turn on above Vgs=Vth with a large gate Q during transition and then reduce RdsOn sharply with Vgs until they become linear resistors .. which is why I suggest change Vgs R ratio to get more Vgs or get the right FET.. **It's nonlinear but still Ohm's Law**

Comment: look at Vgs tolerance of Q1/Q2 and transfer function as a CMOS voltage controlled bipolar switch with nonlinear threshold and wide tolerance, then be wise about matching devices. CMOS logic is very symmetrical 25'to 50 Ohm yours is not matched and insufficient Vgs for Q2 so not reaching potential RdsOn minimum. The IRF needs at least Vgs =6V to switch with low RdsOn. See graph of Q vs Vgs , FET has large rise in Q during transition so C=Q/Vgs and then slope of delta Q/delta V indicates huge rise in C during transition. This is true for all FETs and reason why CMOS has logic switched  I noise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two important types of losses in a mosfet: Conduction losses and switching losses.

1. **Conduction losses**: This occurs when the mosfet is already switched on and is conducting current. You will have some resistance from drain to source. This resistance changes with the gate voltage. In this circuit, when Vch is pulled low, Vgs is about -4V. The resistance Rds will cause a small voltage drop. At 0.75A, for the Si2351DS you'll get Vds=0.075V, but for the IRF9540N it will be closer to Vds=0.4V. You get 0.3W loss just from conduction losses.
2. **Switching losses**: The gate of a mosfet acts as a small capacitor. While the gate charges, some current can flow trough the device, but there will still be a voltage drop across it. This is demonstrated in the following graph.
   [image: Mosfet switching losses]
   Switching losses also occur when switching the mosfet off.
   For Q1: lets look at the input capacitance of the Si2351DS vs the IRF9540N, which is 250 vs 1300 pF respectively. It will take 5 times longer to charge the gate of the IRF9540N, so the switching losses increase. The same goes for Q3: 2sk3539 vs IRLB8721PbF (1077 vs 12 pF respectively.) In addition to this the IRLB8721PbF is fully switched on at a Vds of 6V whereas 2sk3539 is only requires 3V. This is important, because Q3 is used to accelerate the charging of the gate of Q1.

A good solution would be to use the same mosfets as used in the reference design or something comparable, not just any mosfet.

I hope this helps!

-kv

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! I'm trying to learn how I can do this kind of calculations by myself and I'm a bit lost. How did you calculate Vgs -4? How did you get Vds=0.075V and Vds=0.5V and lastly how did you calculate 0.3W of losses? That would be immensely helpful to understand it :)
If I look at the datasheet I see Rds(on) = 0.117Ω for IRF9540N and 0.115 at Vgs = - 4.5 V for Si2351DS, this is why I chose it. I realize now Rds changes with voltage, how do I calculate it for particular voltage?

Comment: Also how to determine when the mosfet is fully on? I couldn't find 6V in IRLB8721PbF datasheet. Is it "Gate Threshold Voltage"? In any case - thanks a lot for the answer!

Comment: Most of this is just ohms law and graphs from the datasheets.

1. Vgs is set by R6 and R9. They act as a voltage divider when Vch is pulled to ground. My calculations were based on 9V input voltage. You get Vgs = Vin * R9 / (R6 + R9) - Vin. For 9V this is -3.71V. For 12V this would be -4.95V.

___ 2. Vds was determined using the Vgs vs Rds graph in the datasheet or the Vds vs Ids graph.

__ 3. P = V * I

__ 4. You can look at voltage vs current graphs and determine the resistance from those too.

__ 5. At 6V Rds(on)=8Ohm. You could go beyond 6V to get marginally better conductivity.

Comment: Thanks for excellent explanation!
I was looking at alternatives given my new knowledge and I found one which seems to fit for Q1: IRLML2246TRPbF http://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irlml2246pbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a401535664c91f25f2
Rds at 4.95v is 0.08 Ohm, capacitance is 220pf.
For Q3 I can get FK3503010L http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheets/panasonic/FK350601.pdf which cited as an alternative to 2sk3539 - they have the same Rds and input capacitance. What do you think?

Comment: Also I was wondering - if I increase R3 to 530Ohm, then my Vgs will be -6.36V. Vgs = 12 * 470 / (470 + 530) - 12 = -6.36
Would it cause any problems?

Comment: Don't you mean R6? Sure you can experiment with the higher Vgs. It might be wise to scale down the values of R6 and R9 so the gate charges quicker. Check how much current Vch can sink.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant R6. I'm going to try experimenting with the values. Anyway, do you think IRLML2246TRPbF would be an appropriate replacement for Si2351DS if I keep resistors as is?

Comment: Mosfets finally arrived today!
Just replacing Q3 with FK3503010L significantly reduced the temperature on Q1 (it was very warm, but I could hold my finger on it without any problems).
Replacing Q1 with IRLML2246TRPbF reduced it's temperature (and size :)), so now it's just slightly warm.

Comment: I'm glad it worked out!